# How to set svnsync to continually retry if connection breaks? (unix scripting needed?)

Tags: svn, unix, synchronization, repository, svnsync

I'm running svnsync as a background process,

```
nohup svnsync synchronize svn://www.example.com/repos &
```

But sometimes the source SVN repository / server crashes. Can I set svnsync or configure something that would periodically retry the sync?

Note that:

1. svnsync fails to connect with the error message:

> svnsync: PROPFIND request failed on
>   '/repos/abc'
>
> svnsync: PROPFIND of
>   '/repos/abc': could not connect to
>   server (http://a.bc.de)

1. Locks are left in place that need to be cleared with the following command

> svn pdel --revprop -r 0 svn:sync-lock --username myusername svn://www.example.com/repos

Comment: There does not appear to be a solution.... in any case I manually checked the process over several days and restarted it whenever it broke...

Answer (score 1):

The way you're running this means that it'll stop after it's done, so it's by no means continuous.

I would use a cron job to repeatedly call svnsync at intervals. I wouldn't recommend cleaning the locks automatically, because they're there for a good reason.

In what way does the server/repository crash? Try running `svnadmin verify` on the repository.

Comment: this would be the source repository? I dont have that access... :(